# How do I stop the audio from overlapping?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple javascript function which plays an audio file when I click on a word. Here's the HTML code:

```
<div class="word">

  <div class="AR" data-audio="1.mp3">text 1</div>
  <div class="AR" data-audio="2.mp3">text 2</div>
  <div class="AR" data-audio="3.mp3">text 3</div>

</div>
```

And here's the javascript code:

```
$('.AR').on('click', function (e) {

  // Stopping the audio from overlapping
  var e = event || window.event;
  e.cancelBubble = true;
  if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();

  var this_element = event.target || event.srcElement;
  var audio_file = this_element.dataset.audio;
  var audio_url = "https://example.com/" + audio_file;

  if (e.mp3) {
    if(e.mp3.paused) e.mp3.play();
    else e.mp3.pause();
  } else {
      e.mp3 = new Audio(audio_url);
      e.mp3.play();
  }

});
```

The function just gets the `dataset` value from the clicked element and plays the audio. This work fine but playback of the audio overlaps each other if I click a div multiple times in quick succession, or if I click on another element while the previous audio is still playing. I've also tried adding `stopPropagation()` function but that doesn't work. What's wrong here?

Comment: Nothing about stopPropagation is going to do anything about multiple clicks on different elements. You need to detect if a sound is currently playing, and either queue up the next sound or prevent it from playing entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways this can be achieved.

One approach would be to associate `Audio` objects with each of your DIV elements with the `.AR` class via jQuery's `.data()` method. This association could be done as an initialisation step for all elements matching the `.AR` selection via the `.each()` method.

Your `click` logic could then be updated so that all audio objects, associated with `.AR` elements, are paused and stopped before playback of the clicked element begins - this would avoid the "overlapping audio" effect that you're noticing:

```js
$('.AR')
.each(function() {
  
  /*
  For each .AR element, preload and instantiate
  an audio object. Associate the audio instance
  with this element (via "audio-object" data key)
  */
  $(this).data('audio-object', new Audio());
  
})
.on('click', function (e) {
  
  /*
  When .AR element is clicked, iterate all .AR
  elements, and pause/reset the associated audio 
  instances (if audio has src attribute).
  This has the effect of "stopping all audio" for
  .AR elements on the page
  */
  $('.AR').each(function() {
    var audio = $(this).data('audio-object');

    if(audio.src) {
      audio.pause();
      audio.currentTime = 0;
    }
  });
  
  /*
  Now that all audio objects for .AR elements 
  have stopped playing, start playing the actual
  audio object for the .AR element that was clicked.

  If the audio object has no src attribute, assign
  to load this audio object instance.
  
  */
  var clickedAudio = $(this).data('audio-object');

  if(!clickedAudio.src) {
    clickedAudio.src = $(this).data('audio');
  }

  clickedAudio.play();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="word">

  <div class="AR" data-audio="https://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3">text 1</div>
  <div class="AR" data-audio="https://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3">text 2</div>
  <div class="AR" data-audio="https://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3">text 3</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly and does what I wanted from the other comment. However there's one problem. This code preloads all the mp3 file on the page reload. So for example, if I have 200 of these elements, the function downloads all those mp3's automatically at once and then plays them from cache. This is not what I want because eventually I'll be having even more elements. Any solutions to this?

Comment: @MarwanAnsari just updated the answer - does that help?

Comment: Your updated code worked perfectly! Thanks a lot for helping me out :)

Answer (score 1):

You should check if the audio is playing, and if it is, just don't play the next sound.
I've altered your code to do that:

```
function play(mp3) {
  if (!playing.paused) {
    return;
  }
  mp3.play();
  playing = mp3;
}
$('.AR').on('click', function () {

  // Stopping the audio from overlapping
  var e = event || window.event;
  e.cancelBubble = true;
  if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();

  var this_element = event.target || event.srcElement;
  var audio_file = this_element.dataset.audio;
  var audio_url = audio_file;

  if (!e.mp3) {
    e.mp3 = new Audio(audio_url);
  }

  play(e.mp3);

});
```

Here's a live demo:
http://plnkr.co/edit/5orIJefLP7q6ufeTJ6fq?p=preview

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks a lot! However, is there a way that if I click on a new element, the previous audio stops playing and the new audio starts playing?